# C EXC_BAD_ACCESS with string manipulation

Tags: c, string

I get a EXC_BAD_ACCESSS when trying to run my function to reverse a string. I don't know if this is an Xcode problem or coding.

Code:

```
char *reverse(char *input, int left, int right) {
    if(left>=right)
        return input;

    char temp = input[left];//sets temp = to rightmost
    input[left]=input[right];//swaps front with back
    input[right]=temp;//swaps back with front
    reverse(input, left+1, right-1);

    return "";
}
```

Comment: Are you passing a constant: `reverse("HELLO", 0, 4)`? Also, the last line of the func should return the result of the recursive call.

Answer (score 0):

If you pass constant string the program will crash since `input[left] = input[right]` would be illegal. For recursive call you have to call function in return:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *reverse(char *input, int left, int right) {

    if(left>=right)
        return input;

    char temp = input[left];//sets temp = to rightmost

    input[left] = input[right];//swaps front with back

    input[right] = temp;//swaps back with front

     return(reverse(input, left+1, right-1));
 }

int main(void)
{
    char str[] = { '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', 0 };

    char *r =  reverse(str, 0, 6);

    printf("RSTR: %s",r);

    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
RSTR: 7654321
```

Comment: Thank you, it was because when I called it, i was calling it a char* but for some reason, it the compiler did not like that so switching it over to a char[] helped solve the problem.

Comment: @JordanHeath - you really should understand why *"the compiler did not like"* -- it's important. If you declare your input as `char *str = "somestring";` that creates `str` as a pointer to a *'string-literal'* in *read-only* memory. When you try and change characters (BOOM SegFault). When you declare with `char str[] = "somestring";` you create a character array that is mutable.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Thank you so much for clarifying this to me. It makes sense why it crashes because you can not modify read-only values. What if i scanned in a user input to a pointer such as char *str.... why does this not cause a SegFault? Is it because a user input isn't a 'string literal'?

Comment: As long as the thing the pointer points to is moifyable, then you are fine, e.g. `char buf[256] = "", char *p = buf; printf ("enter something: "); fgets (p, sizeof buf, stdin); for (int i = 0; i < strlen (p); i++) *p++ = 'a'; p = buf;` is fine. (you would read the string into `buf` using the pointer `p` and then loop over each char changing it to `'a'`). All A-OK because `buf` is mutable (modifyable, whatever you want to call it)